# PowerShell login failed for database but no exception

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I'm writing a database scripting tool using SMO and Powershell. However, no error is being thrown if the user has access to the server but cannot access the database.

```
$SMOserver = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') -argumentlist $server
$db = $SMOserver.databases[$dbname]
```

Currently, it makes the connection to the server but the second line simply assigns $db to null and proceeds without any sort of exception being thrown. Is there a good way to handle this?  I do not want to just check to see if $db is null.

Comment: `I do not want to just check to see if $db is null.` ... ahem, why not ?!?

Comment: I'd like to error message to be as descriptive as possible. And would like it to "catch" errors that I have not accounted for. Maybe it's not the user login issue but database not being present? Single user mode? If there's setting in PowerShell that is suppressing this exception being thrown, turning this exception on would be my preference. I've already implemented it with the null check. Looking to see if I can make it better. =)

Comment: Have you tried running a SQL Profiler on the instance to see what might be the actual problem? As you state, it could be several different things, and possibly not even a DB issue (but a PS one)

Comment: @brazilianldsjaguar, the issue in this particular case is the user permissioning in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have a good point in wanting a precise error handling. I'm not especially familiar with SMO, but here's a few ideas (a little too long for a simple comment).

I'm surprised that you get null as a result in your case. For the moment you're more or less just getting an item off the list of databases (equivalent of querying `sys.databases` from the `master` DB, I suppose). Does your user have access rights to the server at all (I do not see credentials in your snippet, are they removed on purpose ?) ?

Maybe you could check the result of a command like this one (output as you see fit) :

```
$SMOserver.databases | Select Name, Status, UserAccess ;
```

in order to check if you get any DB listed.

If not, your user probably doesn't have sufficient rights on the server in general (but just enough not to cause an exception on `New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server')` ?).